# Send response to file request?

Tags: java, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

One of my client put the file request under directory placeorder with below configuration in CAMEL

```
<route id="FileToJMS">
  <from uri="file:target/placeorder" />
  <to uri="jms:incomingOrders" />
</route>
```

Once processing is done from incomingOrders, i want to send the some response to customer who initiated file request. How can i achieve it with CAMEL (probably using request reply or return address pattern). Any ideas?

Comment: In what format is the response? Web service, file drop, jms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
<route id="FileToJMS">
  <from uri="file:target/placeorder" />
  <to uri="jms:incomingOrders" />
  <to uri="mock:response"/>
</route>
```

replace "mock:response" with whatever component you want to send the response with